# Ant Design: remove the divider line between table rows

Tags: reactjs, antd

When making a Table in Ant Design, there are always gray divider lines between each row. Is there a way to style these divider lines or completely remove them from the table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should override the `antd` table styles

```
.ant-table-tbody > tr > td {
  border: none
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to work for me. I'm wondering if maybe I'm defining it in the wrong place. I'm applying the table in a Next.js project, and I added your style inside a component-level CSS. Is there a different place this should go in?

Comment: @user2921009 Somewhere you might import the `antd` table styles, make sure that above stylesheets you are injecting are after that (to override defaults).

Comment: The import should look something like `import 'antd/dist/antd.css'`

Comment: Yeah, I found that point now. I made an overrides.css file and called it in the _app file in Next making sure it is imported after the antd.css, and it did work. Thank you for you help. Of course, now I have the issue of how to make this override local rather than global for the whole app, but that's more of a Next issue than Antd, so I'll leave that to a another question. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using css-modules in your Nextjs application, you can override table styles like this:

in them component file:

```
import classes from './Comp.module.css';
function Comp(props){
  ...
  return (
    <Table
       ...
       className={classes.customTable}
   />
  )
}
```

and in the Comp.module.css file:

```
.customTable .ant-table-tbody > tr > td{
    border: none
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your solution and it didn't work for me at first, but then I discovered that the combination of your answer with Artyom does. I had to import an overriding CSS file in the _app.ts file, but that overrides all instances of Table across the entire application. When I changed it to your code it finally worked. So, that you for your help too.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will help someone: I had a task to remove the line (border bottom) in the last row of the table. The solution is:

```
.ant-table-tbody > tr:last-child > td {
    border: none
}
```

style for all Table.